# How to read the first 10000 lines from file and write them in another? PHP

Tags: php, file

Hello i have this code:

```
      file1 = file_get_contents("read.txt");
$path2 = "write.txt";
$file2 = file_get_contents($path2);
if ($file1 !== $file2){
    file_put_contents($path2, $file1);
    echo "working"; 
}
```

how can i get the first 10000 lines or more from the read.txt file and write them in write.txt ?

Comment: file() creates an array, an array is indexed

Comment: Use a loop, reading a line from one, writing to the other, with a counter

Comment: better to use generators http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Comment: Can you show me how to do that with the code ? Thank you.

Comment: You could use the linux `split` function I'd think, assuming you are using linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this reading the entire file, but it would be better to use streams and only read the data you need.

```
<?php
$source="file.txt";
$destination="file2.txt";
$requiredLines=10000;

//compare the modification times, if source is newer than destination - then we do our work
if(filemtime($source)>filemtime($destination)){         
    //work out maximum length of file, as one line may be the whole file.
    $filesize = filesize($source);

    //open file for reading - this doesnt actually read the file it allows us to "stream" it
    $sourceHandle = fopen($source, "r");

    //open file for writing
    $destinationHandle = fopen($destination, "w");

    $linecount=0;
    //loop through file until we reach the end of the file (feof) or we reach the desired number of lines
    while (!feof($sourceHandle) && $linecount++<$requiredLines) { 
        //read one line
        $line = stream_get_line($sourceHandle, $filesize, "\n"); 
        //write the line
        fwrite($destinationHandle,$line);
    }
    //close both files
    fclose($sourceHandle);
    fclose($destinationHandle);
}
```

You can find more info on streams here: [Understanding PHP Streams](https://www.sitepoint.com/%EF%BB%BFunderstanding-streams-in-php/)

Comment: Can you make it to write not in one line please

Comment: stream_get_line includes the line ending - if you are seeing "one line" then your text editor may not support unix line endings. But as this is being copied you would expect to see the same issue in your source file